# Cant run my Executable on .Net Framework 2.0

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, httpwebrequest

My problem is simple I have my application which was perfectly executing under framework 2.0, but recently I upgraded my code to add few lines.

```
        ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 500
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100
        ServicePointManager.EnableDnsRoundRobin = False
        ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 1000
        ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(False, 500, 500)
```

Now when I comment these, the application is executed flawlessly, but when included program requires Framework 2.0 SP2 upgrade, I searched MSDN for this but looks like this is available from Framework 1.1

I dont want my users to upgrage to SP2 for such minor things but cant also remove this from my code, Is there an alternate to achieve similar `ServicePointManager` settings without a Framework Upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem line is

> ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive

and is [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.settcpkeepalive.aspx) only in .NET 2.0 SP2 and up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but is there an alternate in Framework 2.0